# Why does the MongoDB MMS automation agent use so much CPU?

Tags: mongodb-mms

I've deployed a cluster of 4 shards on the same machine using MongoDB's MMS automation agent and I'm observing relatively high CPU usage by the agent process (20-30% CPU constantly).

I checked out the logs at `/var/log/mongodb-mms-automation/automation-agent-verbose.log` and it seems like the agent might be stuck in a loop - the output repeats itself constantly.

Is this normal?

**EDIT: Version**

Agent version 1.2.3.704

**EDIT: Added graphs**

Here are some graphs showing CPU usage over the past 12 hours on the machine hosting the cluster. Notice how the agent uses about **twice** the CPU of the entire cluster, constantly!

Total usage by `mongod` processes:

[image: mongod processes total usage]

Total usage by `mongodb-mms-automation-agent` process:

[image: mongodb-mms-automation-agent usage]

Comment: You have deployed 4 shards on the same machine and you expect CPU usage to be low?

Comment: The `mongod` processes are all using below 5%. The automation agent is using more CPU than my entire cluster combined (`mongod`s + `mongos`, 6 processes total). That's what concerns me.

Comment: Could you submit a ticket to the [MMSSUPPORT](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MMSSUPPORT) project in MongoDB JIRA? Be sure to include your MMS group name.